# How to reuse Lambda esbuild config in SAM template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-sam, esbuild

I have a SAM template with two Lambda functions using a NodeJS runtime that are built from TypeScript to JavaScript using esbuild:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Globals:
  Function:
    Architectures:
      - x86_64
    CodeUri: src/
    Runtime: nodejs18.x

Resources:
  GetFooFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: functions/getFoo.handler
      Events:
        GetFoo:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /foo/{id}
            Method: GET
    Metadata: # Duplicated esbuild properties here
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: 'es2020'
        Sourcemap: true
        External: ['@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb']
        EntryPoints:
          - functions/getFoo.ts
  PutFooFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: functions/putFoo.handler
      Events:
        PutFoo:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /foo/{id}
            Method: PUT
    Metadata: # Duplicated esbuild properties here
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        Minify: true
        Target: 'es2020'
        Sourcemap: true
        External: ['@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb']
        EntryPoints:
          - functions/putFoo.ts
```

However, I don't like that I need to copy/paste the `Metadata` into each Lambda resource. And if I make changes to my esbuild config, I have to duplicate the change N times.

Is there a simpler way to share the esbuild config across all Lambdas? It doesn't let me add `Metadata` under `Globals` and I'm not sure if esbuild can read from a separate config file.

Comment: It's not a direct solution, but I've been exploring the use of Jinja2 as a preprocessor for my templates so that repetitive blocks like this can be parameterized. See: https://cloud-withus.medium.com/how-to-create-jinja2-with-cloudformation-aafcec2cbefc

Answer (score 1):

I felt the same way and used `AWS::Include transform` to handle the following.

```
# template.yaml
MyFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    ...
  Metadata:
    Fn::Transform:
      Name: 'AWS::Include'
      Parameters: { Location: template_metadata_for_esbuild.yaml }
```

```
# template_metadata_for_esbuild.yaml
BuildMethod: esbuild
BuildProperties:
  Format: esm
  Minify: false
  OutExtension:
    - .js=.mjs
  Target: "es2020"
  Sourcemap: true
  EntryPoints: 
    - app.ts
  External:
    - "<package-to-exclude>"
```

- AWS::Include transform - AWS CloudFormation
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After that, I ended up using `Makefile`.
The reason is that I wanted to use esbuild's `Drop labels`, but I couldn't set it in `BuildProperties`.

- Drop labels
  https://esbuild.github.io/api/#drop-labels

I was concerned that the Makefiles would be scattered around each Function and that the contents would be duplicated, but I was able to consolidate them by referring to the following structure.

- aws-sam-typescript-layers-example/Makefile at master - Envek/aws-sam-typescript-layers-example
  https://github.com/Envek/aws-sam-typescript-layers-example/blob/master/Makefile

After trying both, I personally like the Makefile support.
Anyway, it seems to be a good choice according to the requirements of your project.

The following is a reference of the work that was necessary in my project due to this change.

- Change the `CodeUri` of each Function to the directory where the Makefile exists.

  - However, it may be a good thing that we were able to move `CodeUri` to `Globals`.
- With the change of `CodeUri`, reorganize the directory structure of the project if necessary.
- Put the esbuild configuration in `build.ts`.

  - Put the contents of BuildProperties into scripts in package.json in the form of CLI options.
  - However, it became difficult to read, so we decided to use a file format.

I hope this will be of some help to you.